# How do I copy conditional rendering in Excel to multiple rows quickly?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel Spreadsheet with the following data:

[image: Spreadsheet]

The 1st column is the value I want to compare against. On a row by row basis I want to check to see if the other values in that row match the 1st columns value, if it doesn't then I want to highlight the cell red.

I have figured out how to do this by going through each row 1-by-1 and adding the conditional rendering rule but the file is about 200 rows long so will take me some time.

I was just wondering whether this was possible to do **quicker**?

An example below for further understanding:

```
If A2:A10 does not equal A1 - fill the cell red
If B2:B10 does not equal B1 - fill the cell red
If C2:C10 does not equal C1 - fill the cell red
```

EDIT:
Trying the solutions in the comments renders the following:
[image: Conditional Formatting]

**Expected Output**:

This is what I want it to do using just 1 row as an example. I want the value in `Column A` to be the value that the rest of the row is compared against. And when the rows numbers do not match those in `Column A` they should be filled/highlighted to show that they don't match. Much like `L1` on my example - It doesn't match that of `A1` so it is highlighted. I want to do this but for every row and compare the values as stated above.
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: your formula would be: `=AND(A1<>A$1,A1<>"")` and you `Applies to:` would be `=$A$1:$C$300`  One rule no need to create one for each row.  Excel will iterate correctly.

Comment: Sorry where do I find the ```Applies to:``` box? When using Conditional Formatting I don't see this option.

Comment: it is in the conditional format manager.

Comment: @Adam-Foot you need to select the range first then from `Home Tab` --> Under `Styles Group` --> Click `Conditional Formatting` --> Click `New` --> `Format Rule Box` --> Last Option --> `Use A Formula To Determine Which Cells To Format` --> Under Edit Rule Description --> Enter the `Formula` as given above --> Click `Format` --> From `Fill Tab` --> Choose Desired `Color` --> Press `OK` --> Done

Comment: For some reason I can't get this working. It just fills the entire sheet red for me apart from a few values about 100 rows down. I think it is comparing the values in row 1 rather than comparing the values in column 1 as it leaves all of row 1 unfilled - Unless I am doing something wrong

Comment: @Adam-Foot try using this `=AND(A$1<>A2,A$1<>"")`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this fills the entire sheet red - I have attached a 2nd image to my question for your reference.

Comment: @Adam-Foot it will be helpful to show your expected output. Do you want to compare each cell to cell like apple to apple wise.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I have added the expected output above, hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: @Adam-Foot so you are basically comparing column wise right and not row wise

Comment: Yes - I believe this is what my original question was asking but the wording could have confused things.

Comment: @Adam-Foot use this formula `=AND($A1<>A1,A1<>"")` and i have shown in answers as well for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is what you need to do use the formula in conditional formatting as shown below

```
=AND($A1<>A1,A1<>"")
```

[image: CONDITIONAL FORMATTING COLUMN WISE]

Comment: Thank you this has worked.

Comment: @Adam-Foot thank you for sharing the feedback, i am glad it worked for you!